# Get the N iteration of an SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a way to get the N iteration of an SQL query ?

For example, if I want the second iteration :

**Backup**

| id | id_device | nb_cut |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 222 | 853 |
| 10 | 5 | 698 |
| 9 | 222 | 589 |
| 8 | 5 | 123 |
| 7 | 222 | 456 |
| ... | ... | ... |

```
SELECT nb_cut FROM Backup WHERE id_device = 5 ORDER BY id DESC;
```

This query return **698**. But I want the seconde iteration whose result would be **123**.

Comment: Oh, wait, I get it. You have 2 rows with `id_device = 5`. You want the second one in the result. You could use [LIMIT](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-limit.aspx) for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [LIMIT OFFSET](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html)

```
SELECT nb_cut 
FROM Backup 
WHERE id_device = 5  
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1, 1;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/qOOw2LJl

The query shown above gets data starting the second row and limits the results to 1.

Answer (score 1):

Literally the second result over a specific resultset filtered by id_device .... exists limit offset but this one could introduce you to a new world ;)

```sql
SELECT 
    nb_cut 
FROM (
  select 
     *, 
     row_number() OVER ( PARTITION BY id_device ORDER BY id DESC) as iteration 
  from Backup
) as t 
WHERE id_device = 5 and iteration = 2
```

Look for "window functions" on the web for explanation

Comment: This [does actually work](https://dbfiddle.uk/sH_r47Jt), but I think it deserves an explanation. What does it actually do?

Comment: the inner subquery gets the original data  with another column "iteration" that is the row_number over a partition defined by id_device and an order defined by their id.

Comment: If you run only the subquery probably you can see what happens....  check on the net window functions in mysql and check what they can do ;)

Comment: that kind of window function let you "emulate" a group by function without actually grouping and let you filter in each group.... that kind of approach is nice in order to avoid some complicated nested queries or temporary tables in order to filter data of some grouping with some particular criteria.

Comment: @GicuAftene *but this one could introduce you to a new world*, In this particular case it is costly and redundant using a subquery

Comment: It's a clever solution, but rather more complex than just a LIMIT. I actually meant that the answer should include an explanation.

Comment: This solution had the main scope of introducing people into something more advanced. Giving only the solution to "Getting the second iteration of a query" it's something that doesn't let the newbie to learn and discover something new. I added only this answer, without giving an optimized one, because the question was already answered with a correct and easy solution.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware yeah you're right so i edited the answer with a search keywork in order to let people to look on web.